# Special numbers challenge in programming

Tags: algorithm

First, sorry for my bad English.
Special numbers are numbers that the sum of the digits is divisible to the number of the digit. 

*Example:* 135 is a special number because the sum of the digits is 1+3+5 = 9, the number of the digit is 3, and 9 is divisible to 3 because 9 % 3 == 0. 
2,3,9,13,17,15,225, 14825 are also special numbers.

**Requirement:**

Write a program that read the number n (n <= 10^6) from a file named SNUMS.INP (SNUMS.INP can contain up to 10^6 numbers) and print the result out into the file SNUMS.OUT. Number n is the order of the special number and the result will be that special number in n order (sorry I don't know how to express it).

*Example:* n = 3 means you have to print out the 3rd special number which is 3, n = 10 you have to print out 10th special number which is 11, n = 13 you have to print out 13th special number which is 17, n = 15 you have to print out 15th special number which is 20.


The example bellow will demonstrate the file SNUMS.INP and SNUMS.OUT (Remember: SNUMS.INP can contain up to 10^6 numbers)

SNUMS.INP:

2

14

17

22

SNUMS.OUT:

2

19

24

35

I have my own alogrithm but the the running time exceeds 1 second (my SNUMS.INP has 10^6 numbers). So I need the optimal alogrithm so that the running time will be less than or equal 1s.
Guys I decide to post my own code which is written in Java, it always take more than 4 seconds to run. Could you guys please suggest some ideas to improve or how to make it run faster

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("SNUMS.INP");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        int order = 1;
        int i = 1;
        int[] special = new int[1000000+1];

        // Write all 10^6 special numbers into an array named "special"
        while (order <= 1000000)
        {
            if (specialNumber(i) == true)
            {
                special[order] = i;
                order++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        // Write the result to file
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("SNUMS.OUT");
        outputFile.println(special[inputFile.nextInt()]);
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
            outputFile.println(special[inputFile.nextInt()]);
        outputFile.close();
    }

    public static boolean specialNumber(int i)
    {
        // This method check whether the number is a special number
        boolean specialNumber = false;
        byte count=0;
        long sum=0;
        while (i != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (i % 10);
            count++;
            i = i / 10;
        }
        if (sum % count == 0) return true;
        else return false;
     }
}
```

This is file SNUMS.INP (sample) contains 10^6 numbers if you guys want to test.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOJpa2dAZlUNkE3YmMwZmlBOTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like you should *precompute* `1e6` beautiful numbers and then perform the file

Comment: I know but the alogarithm will take more than 1 second. I need the running MUST be less than or equal 1 second

Comment: Well, could you provide your implementation then? Let's see where we can improve it

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it in `0.6` seconds on C# 6.0 (.Net 4.6 IA-64) at Core i7 3.2 GHz with HDD 7200 rpc; hope that precompution will be fast enough at your workstation:

```
// Precompute beautiful numbers
private static int[] BeautifulNumbers(int length) {
  int[] result = new int[length];

  int index = 0;

  for (int i = 1; ; ++i) {
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int v = i; v > 0; sum += v % 10, ++count, v /= 10)
      ;

    if (sum % count == 0) {
      result[index] = i;

      if (++index >= result.Length)
        return result;
    }
  } 
}
```

...

```
// Test file with 1e6 items
File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\SNUMS.INP", Enumerable
  .Range(1, 1000000)
  .Select(index => index.ToString()));
```

...

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

// Precomputed numbers (about 0.3 seconds to be created)
int[] data = BeautifulNumbers(1000000);

// File (about 0.3 seconds for both reading and writing)
var result = File
  .ReadLines(@"D:\SNUMS.INP")
  .Select(line => data[int.Parse(line) - 1].ToString());

File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\SNUMS.OUT", result);

sw.Stop();

Console.Write("Elapsed time {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

The output vary from

```
Elapsed time 516
```

to

```
Elapsed time 660
```

with average elapsed time at about `580` milliseconds

Comment: It's a shame on me to admit that I'm a amateur in programming, I know Java, but I don't know very much about C#, so I don't really understand you code. Could you please tell me about the algorithm, very sorry T.T

Comment: @Nguyen Hoa: be an amateur is quite OK; what's not OK is a messy question. Let's take Java, as you can see, `BeautifulNumbers` method on C# is quite the *same* on Java (as far as I can see `result.Length` should be changed into `result.length` and that's all). Could you convert  `BeautifulNumbers` into java and measure time with `System.nanoTime()` at the target workstation?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the metaphor of abacus implemented below, here are some hints

1. instead of just incrementing with 1 inside a cycle, can we incremente more aggressively? Indeed we can, but with an extra bit of care.

   - first, how much aggressive we can be? Looking to 11 (first special with 2 digits), it doesn't pay to just increment by 1, we can increment it by 2. Looking to 102 (special with 3 digits), we can increment it by 3. Is it natural to think we should use increments equal with the number of digits?
   - now the "extra bit of care" - whenever the "increment by the number of digits" causes a "carry", the naive increment breaks. Because the carry will add `1` to the sum of digits, so that we may need to subtract that one from something to keep the `sum of digits` well behaved.
2. one of the issues in the above is that we jumped quite happily at "first special with N digits", but the computer is not us to see it at a glance. 
   Fortunately, the "first special with N digits" is easy to compute: it is `10^(N-1)+(N-1)` - `10^(N-1)` brings an `1` and the rest is zero, and `N-1` brings the rest to make the sum of digits be the first divisible with `N`. Of course, this will break down if `N > 10`, but fortunately the problem is limited to `10^6` special numbers, which will require at most 7 digits (the millionth specual number is 6806035 - 7 digits);
3. so, we can detect the "first special number with N digits" and we know we should try *with care* to increment it by N. Can we look now better into that "extra care"?.

The code - twice as speedy as the previous one and totally "orthodox" in obtaining the data (via getters instead of direct access to data members).
Feel free to inline:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Abacus {

  static protected int pow10[]=
    {1,10,100,1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000}
  ;
  // the value stored for line[i] corresponds to digit[i]*pow10[i]
  protected int lineValues[];
  protected int sumDigits;
  protected int representedNumber;

  public Abacus() {
    this.lineValues=new int[0];
    this.sumDigits=0;
    this.representedNumber=0;
  }

  public int getLineValue(int line) {
    return this.lineValues[line];
  }
  public void clearUnitLine() {
    this.sumDigits-=this.lineValues[0];
    this.representedNumber-=this.lineValues[0];
    this.lineValues[0]=0;
  }

  // This is how you operate the abacus in real life being asked
  // to add a number of units to the line presenting powers of 10
  public boolean addWithCarry(int units, int line) {
    if(line-1==pow10.length) {
      // don't have enough pow10 stored
      pow10=Arrays.copyOf(pow10, pow10.length+1);
      pow10[line]=pow10[line-1]*10;
    }
    if(line>=this.lineValues.length) {
      // don't have enough lines for the carry
      this.lineValues=Arrays.copyOf(this.lineValues, line+1);
    }
    int digitOnTheLine=this.lineValues[line]/pow10[line];
    int carryOnTheNextLine=0;
    while(digitOnTheLine+units>=10) {
      carryOnTheNextLine++;
      units-=10;
    }
    if(carryOnTheNextLine>0) {
      // we have a carry, the sumDigits will be affected
      // 1. the next two statememts are equiv with "set a value of zero on the line"
      this.sumDigits-=digitOnTheLine;
      this.representedNumber-=this.lineValues[line];

      // this is the new value of the digit to set on the line
      digitOnTheLine+=units;

      // 3. set that value and keep all the values synchronized
      this.sumDigits+=digitOnTheLine;
      this.lineValues[line]=digitOnTheLine*pow10[line];
      this.representedNumber+=this.lineValues[line];

      // 4. as we had a carry, the next line will be affected as well.
      this.addWithCarry(carryOnTheNextLine, line+1);
    }
    else { // we an simply add the provided value without carry
      int delta=units*pow10[line];
      this.lineValues[line]+=delta;
      this.representedNumber+=delta;
      this.sumDigits+=units;
    }
    return carryOnTheNextLine>0;
  }

  public int getSumDigits() {
    return this.sumDigits;
  }

  public int getRepresentedNumber() {
    return this.representedNumber;
  }

  public int getLinesCount() {
    return this.lineValues.length;
  }


  static public ArrayList<Integer> specials(int N) {
    ArrayList<Integer> ret=new ArrayList<>(N);
    Abacus abacus=new Abacus();
    ret.add(1);
    abacus.addWithCarry(1, 0); // to have something to add to
    int increment=abacus.getLinesCount();
    while(ret.size()<N) {
      boolean hadCarry=abacus.addWithCarry(increment, 0);
      if(hadCarry) {
        // need to resynch the sum for a perfect number
        int newIncrement=abacus.getLinesCount();
        abacus.clearUnitLine();
        if(newIncrement!=increment) {
          // we switched powers of 10
          abacus.addWithCarry(newIncrement-1, 0);
          increment=newIncrement;
        }
        else { // simple carry
          int digitsSum=abacus.getSumDigits();
          // how much we should add to the last digit to make the sumDigits
          // divisible again with the increment?
          int units=increment-digitsSum % increment;
          if(units<increment) {
            abacus.addWithCarry(units, 0);
          }
        }
      }
      ret.add(abacus.getRepresentedNumber());
    }
    return ret;
  }

  // to understand how the addWithCarry works, try the following code
  static void add13To90() {
    Abacus abacus; // starts with a represented number of 0
    // line==1 means units of 10^1
    abacus.addWithCary(9, 1); // so this should make the abacus store 90
    System.out.println(abacus.getRepresentedNumber());
    // line==0 means units of 10^0
    abacus.addWithCarry(13, 0); 
    System.out.println(abacus.getRepresentedNumber()); // 103
  }

  static public void main(String[] args) {
    int count=1000000;
    long t1=System.nanoTime();
    ArrayList<Integer> s1=Abacus.specials(count);
    long t2=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("t:"+(t2-t1));
  }
}
```

---

Constructing the numbers from their digits is bound to be faster.

Remember [the abacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus)? Ever used one?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Specials {

  static public ArrayList<Integer> computeNSpecials(int N) {
    ArrayList<Integer> specials = new ArrayList<>();
    int abacus[] = new int[0]; // at index i we have the digit for 10^i
                               // This way, when we don't have enough specials,
                               // we simply reallocate the array and continue
    while (specials.size() < N) {
      // see if a carry operation is necessary
      int currDigit = 0;
      for (; currDigit < abacus.length && abacus[currDigit] == 9; currDigit++) {
        abacus[currDigit] = 0; // a carry occurs when adding 1
      }
      if (currDigit == abacus.length) { 
        // a carry, but we don't have enough lines on the abacus
        abacus = new int[abacus.length + 1];
        abacus[currDigit] = 1; // we resolved the carry, all the digits below
        // are 0
      } else {
        abacus[currDigit]++; // we resolve the carry (if there was one), 
        currDigit = 0;       // now it's safe to continue incrementing at 10^0
      }
      // let's obtain the current number and the sum of the digits
      int sumDigits = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i<abacus.length; i++) {
        sumDigits += abacus[i];
      }
      // is it special?
      if (sumDigits % abacus.length == 0) {
        // only now compute the number and collect it as special
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = abacus.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          number = 10 * number + abacus[i];
        }
        specials.add(number);
      }
    }
    return specials;
  }
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> specials=Specials.computeNSpecials(100);
    for(int i=0; i<specials.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(specials.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your algorithm is creative and fantastic, but I'm very sorry that the running time is about 2.5 second when I manage to use your code with the SNUMS.INP file above. Maybe that's because you use ArrayList which can be take longer runnning time, Anyways, I will try to change Arraylist into usual array, hope it will work

Comment: @NguyenHoa "Anyways, I will try to change Arraylist into usual array, hope it will work" **DON'T!** Instead just take a bit of time and look over the first 100 "special numbers" generated. You may be able to discover a regularity which will allow you to generate them faster. See you in about 2-3 hours if you haven't discovered it by yourself (please let me know if you do), I'll hint you how.

Comment: Hi, after some hours strugglingg, I can quite fully understand your code and your alogrithm as well. About the regularity, at first I think the regularity is when a special number adds its sum of digits will make another special number. Ex: 2 adds its sum of digit (which is 1) = 3, and 3 is a special number, 22 adds 2 = 24 and 24 is a special number, 111 adds 3 = 114 and 114 is a special number. But there are so many exception like 19 adds 2 = 21 and 21 is not a special number. etc. So, your hint is necessary to me now.

Comment: @NguyenHoa Ah, perfect. I'll come back in a bit, just busy not trying to finish something. Until then, **copy/paste those hints into something offline**, I'm going to modify them or perhaps even delete them.

Comment: @NguyenHoa Get first to understand how the `addWithCarry` operates. Then look into the `specials(N)` method.

Comment: Ah, I see your new code above, thank you. Because I don't have much experience in programming, I failed to detect the regularity. However, I'm trying my best to fully understand your code above. And I'm very grateful to your help, you actually help me a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NguyenHoa "understand your code above." it helps if you trace through the code in debug mode an pay attention to how the variables modify.

Comment: @ Adrian Colomitchi Thank you, I know that method and I'm truly applying it  to understand your code

Comment: @NguyenHoa the model could be decribed as in the followings: the `lineValues` store the values of abacus lines (e.g. 42 will be represented by a 2 on `lineValues[0]` and a 40 on the `lineValues[1]`. The `representedNumber` is, of course, the sum of all the `lineValues` - I'm keeping it redundantly to avoid summing all the `lineValues`. The `sumDigits` is self explanatory. Since all this housekeeping variables have a high degree of redundancy (to speed up the operations), the trick is too keep them synchronized (that's what `addWithCarry` and `clearUnitLine` needs to do).

Comment: @NguyenHoa I added some extra comments in `addWithCarry` and a 'demo' method (`add13To90`). Trace through that demo method.

Comment: Ah... yeah! It's become easier to understand now, it's very kind of to explain it to me in detail ^^

Comment: @NguyenHoa Good luck.  (traditionally, on SO, the thanks are expressed by upvoting answers that helped you. Take your time, though)

Comment: I did upvoting your answer, many many times, but a message always shows up and it says that:"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". T.T I don't know why

Comment: Ah, no problem.